# Do money transfer companies have a LEGITIMATE need for a passport copy

Tags: united-kingdom, money-transfer, legal, privacy

Money transfer service Azimo asks for a copy of my passport. I sent it, after having written 'copy' on it, for security reasons. My transfer then was rejected, because 'We weren’t able to verify your document on this occasion'. 
My questions are:

1. Do (UK based) money service companies have a legitimate need to ask for an ID copy?
2. If so, according to UK security legislation, do I have the right to write on the copy, eg: 'Copy for Azimo money transfer 23042020'?

Thanks!

Comment: @Inge Anti-money laundering regulations require them to verify your identity. A passport is a common way of doing this but other forms of photo ID are usually acceptable eg driving licence, national ID. I’m not aware of any restriction preventing you from annotating the copy, in fact eg it’s normal for banks etc to stamp and sign copies when they certify them as a ‘true copy’. Where did you write the annotation? If it obscured details such as name, date of birth or the machine-readable zone data, it’s possible that Azimo’s system couldn’t read the copy.

Comment: http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2019/1511/contents/made

Comment: http://data.consilium.europa.eu/doc/document/PE-72-2017-INIT/en/pdf

Comment: You have the right to amend a copy by writing on it, but the service also has every right to reject said amended document if they see fit.

Comment: It may be hard to define what is a "legitimate need". The companies typically interpret that as "we built our processes around this so we need it" but that can be very different from what the law says. For example, under Czech law it is illegal to take copies of identity documents, yet it doesn't stop all kinds of service providers from insisting on exactly that, just because it's the easiest way for them to record your identity for AML purposes. I suspect there are similar laws in other countries as well.

Comment: "The government" (actually all of them, but let's pretend it's just one big one) wants to see where all the money goes so that if they find out about a crime that involves money, they can see where the money went, so they know who to arrest. Yes, this means you have no privacy.

Comment: Please someone write an actual answer, not just comments :-)